# Measure the similarty between two sequences of letters

Tags: time-series, probability, clustering, matlab, text-mining

I'm trying to measure the similarity between two time-series sequences of letters with different lengths (**e.g. s1=[A;A;A;C;B], s1=[Q;A;A;A;A;A]** ). The order is very important. (**e.g. s3=[A;A;A;C;C;C;C] not equal s4=[C;C;C;C;A;A;A]**)

My question: What is the similarity or disimilarity measure that could be used to measure the distance between two sequences of letters **D(s1,s2)**. Note that I have no knowledge about the distance between A & B ..etc ... it is just a letters (which means A not closer to B comparing to C ..etc). It would be great if you suggest any Matlab function or code

Comment: levenshtein distance could be something to look into

Comment: I had a look to Levenshtein Distance. but it has a problem that does not capture the similarity between long a short sequence with same letters (e.g. s1=[A;A;A;A;A], s2=[A;A;A]]; The D(s1,s2) = 2; where it should be 0!

Comment: You can then extend it. You probably will not find something that will fit your needs perfectly.

Comment: I think this problem can be solved using dynamic programming. But I did not find anything similar so far!

Comment: Omar, there can be developed a great number of (dis)similarity measures to compare sequences. You should know exactly and in details what you want. For example, you say s3 is not equal to s4. How much not equal in that case? Is the similarity is 0 or somewhat still above 0 (while when s3=s4 it is 1)?

Comment: P.S. I once have programmed out an SPSS function (sorry, not Matlab) to compare sequences in quite flexible or general way. The approach is to find and count all equal subsequences in the two sequences while weighting by the length of each such subsequence.

Comment: ttnphns, I'm looking to a similarity measures capture the frequencies of the letters between the two sequences and the order at the same time. e.g. s3 and s4 have 'A' 3 times and 'C' 4 times, but the order in the two sequences are different. In s3 3 A's followed by 4 C's but in s4 4 C's followed by 3 A's.

Comment: Will you agree with a reasoning like that: if s3=s4=`A;A;A;C;C;C;C` than there is 7 equal symbols organized in one equality subsequence lengthed 7. So the numerator of your similarity coefficient is 7*7=49. If s3= as above but s4=`C;C;C;C;A;A;A` then we have 7 equal symbols organized in in two subsequences lengthed 3 and 4. So the numerator will be 3*3+4*4=25.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the classics, i.e.

### [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

and **similar [edit distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)**?

There are plenty of variations, for example some that normalize for length...
You'll have to pick the one that suits your use case best. Or make up your own new variation of that theme.